# Ember data pluralisation strange behavior

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have an ember application with a model named "media". "media" is a singular word. "medias" is the plural one.
I define my model like this :

```
App.Media = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string')
});
```

Normally, "media" is the singular name of my model. So my api return this payload executing `this.store.find('media', 1)`:

```
{
    "media": {
        "id" : 1,
        "name" : "media name"
    }
}
```

This give me an error: `No model was found for 'medium'`.
Ember-data want me to return a payload like this: `{ "medium": {...}}`.
Why does enber-data singularize "media" ? It's already a singular word.

Moreover, adding irregular rule to the inflector don't affect the adapter at all.

`Ember.Inflector.inflector.irregular('media', 'medias');`

A complete example can be found here : http://emberjs.jsbin.com/bobaj/5/edit?js,output

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using [irregular](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/Ember.Inflector.html#method_irregular), use [singular](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/Ember.Inflector.html#method_singular). That is, this works:

```
Ember.Inflector.inflector.singular(/media/i, 'media');
```

And [here's](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/duyowuqu/1/edit?js,console) a JSBin showing that behavior.

Answer (score 0):

This solves my problem:

```
Ember.Inflector.inflector.singular(/([ti])a$/i, '$1a');
Ember.Inflector.inflector.plural(/([ti])a$/i, '$1as');
```